# Getting URL of the top frame

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside a facebook application I need to check what is the top frame (the main window) URL, and show content accordingly.

I tried using the following:

```
if (top.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("facebook.com") <0) { ... }
```

Which works well if the page is not inside an iframe, but when the page is loaded within an iframe (as it does when used as facebook application) the code generates

> "Uncaught TypeError: Property
>   'toString' of object # is not a
>   function".

Is there any way I can fix this code (with cross-browser compatibility - maybe with jQuery)?

Thanks!

Joel

Comment: You can't get at the top location but you can at the parent by using the document.referrer string. See answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are having that you are not allowed to access `top.location` across different document domains.

This is a security feature built in to browsers.

[Read up on XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and why the security precautions are in place :)

You can also learn a great deal by reading about [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: Interesting... So is there any workaround to know if I am currently viewing the page through an iframe or not? (saw your edit about XSS - thanks for that. I understand that access to the top frame cookies, for example, can be problematic. But getting the hostname should be allowed :/ )

Comment: If you are not in an iframe `window.top === window` will return true

Answer (score 11):

It is true that cross origin concerns will prevent you from accessing this top window location. However, if you just want the parent window location of the iframe you can get at it via the `document.referrer` string.

Within your iframe you'd grab the url:

`var parentURL = document.referrer`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer

I've used this successfully in my own iframe apps. Also, be aware that if you navigate within your iframe the referrer will change.

Nicholas Zakas has a write-up on his blog:
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/04/16/getting-the-url-of-an-iframes-parent/

Answer (score 3):

With Martin Jespersen adviced fix, I could check address in iFrame and standart top address:

```
//this is fix for IE
if (!window.location.origin) {
    window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
    }

//and here we will get object of address
var urls = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer: document.location;

//Martins adviced fix for checking if You are not in iFrame    
if (window.top === window) {
    urls = urls.origin;
}

//and now indexOf works in both ways - for iFrame and standart top address
if (urls.indexOf("facebook.com") != -1 ) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
if (self!=top && document.referrer.toLowerCase().indexOf("facebook.com") <0) { ... }
```

...as long as you don't navigate inside the frame.

But it's not really a good solution ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you need **as much information as possible** about the top page location:

```js
function getTopLinkInfo() {
  var topLinkInfo = {};

  try {
    // Only for same origins
    topLinkInfo.topHref = top.location.href;
  }
  // Security exception: different origins
  catch (error) {
    try {
      var ancestorOrigins = window.location.ancestorOrigins;
      // Firefox doesn't support window.location.ancestorOrigins
      if (ancestorOrigins) {
        topLinkInfo.parentsDomains = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < ancestorOrigins.length; i++) {
          topLinkInfo.parentsDomains.unshift(ancestorOrigins[i]);
        }
      }

      // Sometimes referrer refers to the parent URL (but not always,
      // e.g. after iframe redirects).
      var bottomW = window;
      var topW = window.parent;
      topLinkInfo.parentsReferrers = [];
      // In case of empty referrers
      topLinkInfo.parentsHrefs = [];

      while (topW !== bottomW) {
        topLinkInfo.parentsReferrers.unshift(bottomW.document.referrer);
        topLinkInfo.parentsHrefs.unshift(bottomW.location.href);
        bottomW = bottomW.parent;
        topW = topW.parent;
      }
    } catch (error) {/* Permission denied to access a cross-origin frame */}
  }
  return topLinkInfo;
}

var result = getTopLinkInfo();
console.table(result);
console.info(result);
```