# Get top window url from frame/iframe in different domain

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I have a web page with some javascript inside that will be embedded as iframe in different websites. I need to adjust the behaviour of my page according to the website in which it's being run. For this purpose, I tried to read `top.location.href` from my page, but that raised an error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://website.url
>   from frame with URL http://mypage.url. Domains, protocols and ports
>   must match.

Is there some way to go around this?

Comment: No, that's not possible for arbitrary websites.

Comment: I've provided an answer below and in the duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903351/getting-url-of-the-top-frame/19438476#19438476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as you stated the same origin policy and it is in place for security reasons. Without changing the users browser there is no way around it.

Comment: I was hoping there were some other way to get that piece of information. Still I don't understand why modern browsers are so strict and consider harmful for a frame to read its top url.

Answer (score 12):

In the most common case you can indeed retrieve the parent url of the iframe. If the iframe is just one level deep this method will work:

`var parentURL = document.referrer`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer

I've used this method when creating iframe widgets. Just remember that if you want the top level window location, but it is not the parent window of your iframe...you won't be able to get it. Also, if your widget navigates within the iframe the referrer will then change.

Yet another excellent write-up by Nicholas Zakas can be found on his blog here:
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/04/16/getting-the-url-of-an-iframes-parent/

Comment: Why the down vote? This works and will likely be useful for others to know.

Comment: Edit: I didnt downvote, but maybe someone did because it does not necesarily give you the top location. But good info thanks.

Comment: It wont work when both the iframe and the top location are not on the same protocol.